# Чи тотожні терміни “незаконний” та “протизаконний”?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, терміни, синоніми

Досить часто у ЗМІ лунають слова "незаконний" та "протизаконний", особливо у кримінальних хроніках українських новин. Стало цікаво: чи є ці слова рівнозначними. Отже,
СУМ-11 пояснює щодо

> **НЕЗАКО́ННИЙ**, а, е. **Який забороняється законом, порушує закон.** *— Треба і можна боротися проти кожного незаконного вчинку (Тулуб, Людолови, І, 1957, 398); Необхідно берегти ліс, не допускати незаконних вирубок (Колг. Укр., 8, 1958, 40);* **// Який суперечить законові, йде врозріз з ним.** *Та й люди нічого незаконного, коли подумати, не вимагали від пана: тільки хотіли за свою роботу мати більший заробіток (Стельмах, І, 1962, 580)*; **// Не оформлений юридично; позашлюбний.** *Звісно, гріх тратити своє добро на незаконних жінок (Стельмах, II, 1962, 94)*.

і стосовно

> **ПРОТИЗАКО́ННИЙ**, а, е. **Який не відповідає закону, суперечить йому.** *Податковий уряд мстився на ній [громаді] при всякій нагоді і старався кождого громадянина знищити протизаконними податками (Март., Тв., 1954, 176)*.

Офіційний сайт Української мови [стверджує](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/n/nezakonnij/36-1-0-10462) що ці слова синоніми:

> Синоніми до слова НЕЗАКОННИЙ: *(крок) протизаконний, с. злочинний, беззаконний; (син) НЕШЛЮБНИЙ*.

Всесвітній словник української мови (WorldwideDictionary.org) [погоджується](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) з "Офіційним сайтом Української мови":

> НЕЗАКО́ННИЙ (який порушує закон, суперечить законові), ПРОТИЗАКО́ННИЙ підсил., БЕЗЗАКО́ННИЙ підсил.; ЛІ́ВИЙ розм. (із сл. рейс, заробіток, робота тощо). - *Негайно виконати ту постанову. І негайно повернути колгоспам усе, що було взято в них незаконним способом (Остап Вишня)*; *Податковий уряд мстився на ній [громаді] при всякій нагоді і старався кождого громадянина знищити протизаконними податками (Лесь Мартович)*; *Стали жовніри.. беззаконні окорми і напитки од людей вимагати (П. Куліш)*. - Пор. несправедли́вий.

І ресурс "Синоніми.укр" [вказує](https://xn--h1aaldafs6o.xn--j1amh/%D0%9D/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) що

> Слово "*незаконний*" має наступні синоніми:
>   (крок) *протизаконний* с. *злочинний* *беззаконний* *(син) нешлюбний*

Отже ці слова є синонімами і тотожні за змістом? 
Але ж, як тоді розуміти більш розширене тлумачення СУМ-11 слова "незаконний"?

Answer (score 5):

[Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005.](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/146968/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) пише:

> **протиправний** -а, -е. Що суперечить правовим нормам, закону, що порушує їх; **незаконний**.

[Словник синонімів української мови. 2014.](http://synonyms_uk.enacademic.com/4525/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) теж подає:

> **незаконний** (який порушує закон, суперечить законові), **протизаконний**, беззаконний, контрафактний (про товар тощо); лівий (зі сл. "рейс", "заробіток", "робота" й под.)

Також М. Іващук у статті [НЕЗАКОННИЙ — БЕЗЗАКОННИЙ — ПРОТИЗАКОННИЙ — АНТИЗАКОННИЙ](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine40-23.pdf) пояснює:

> Прикметник **незаконний**, утворившись за допомогою частки-префікса *не-* від прикметника *законний*, виражає протилежне йому значення, вказуючи на невідповідність установленим законам, на їх порушення.
>
> Прикметник **протизаконний** досить прозорий, тому що префікс *проти-*, співвідносячись з відповідним прийменником, зберігає і його просторове значення спрямованості. Отже, прикметник протизаконний наголошує саме на спрямованості проти закону.
>
> Отже, ці прикметники мають близькі, але не однакові значення. Утворюючи
>   словосполучення з іменниками типу дії, вчинки, прикметник ***протизаконний*** дає змогу найточніше, найоб’єктивніше оцінити дії людини щодо дотримання нею встановлених законів. Використовуємо цей прикметник також аби підкреслити спрямованість дій людини проти законів.
>
> Якщо ми лише констатуємо невідповідність дій установленим законам, потрібно вживати прикметник **незаконний**.

Отже, це синоніми, однак не абсолютні.

Comment: Підтримую і раджу додати приклад. Як варіант: Наприклад: 
 - Закон: Треба вітати людей;
 - Незаконний вчинок: не вітати людей;
 - Протизаконний вчинок: не давати вітати людей (не лише незаконний, але й проти закону).

Answer (score -1):

На прикладі постанови 211 КМУ від 04.04.2020 "Про запобігання поширенню на території України гострої респіраторної хвороби COVID-19, спричиненої коронавірусом SARS-CoV-2"

Вона є незаконною в частині вимог до фізосіб, оскільки закон не наділяє повноваженнями КМУ регулювати особисте життя фізосіб (в тому числі і по закону про цивільний захист, оскільки епідеміологічний поріг не досягнуто та немає науково доведеної ефективності затверджених методів та ролі у показниках смертності)
Вона є протизаконною оскільки прямо суперечить статті 33 конституції.

Тобто 
незаконно - те що законом не врегульовано, не є порушенням в загальному розумінні.
протизаконно - те що законом прямо заборонено, є порушенням.

Comment: Висновок «тобто незаконно - те що законом не врегульовано, не є порушенням в загальному розумінні» трішки дивує. Типу, якщо я на вулиці буду жонглювати пиріжками (я припускаю, що це явно не регулюється: ані забороняються, ані дозволяються) — хіба це буде «незаконно»? Мені здається, треба було б звузити контекст до _рішень/вимог_: рішення/вимогу можна назвати _незаконним_ (_-ою_), якщо його/її автор не мав відповідних повноважень; а _протизаконним_ (_-ою_) — якщо й суть рішення/вимоги суперечить закону (принаймні, такий висновок особисто мені спадає на думку після Вашого прикладу). Чи Ви по-

Comment: іншому про це мислите? Принаймні, я зрозумів Вас так: {незаконні  (у широкому розумінні)} = {юридично необґрунтовані} ∪ {протизаконні}.

Comment: До речі, чи не могли б Ви змінити приклад на якийсь більш давній? (Я жодним чином не хочу стверджувати, що постанова була законною абощо, але просто мені здається, що це надто гаряча тема. Не хочеться, щоб суто мовний сайт перетворювався на сайт медично-юридично-політичних баталій.)

Comment: -1: допис надає тлумачення на основі субʼєктивних суджень. Натомість, на мовному сайті варто користуватися джерелами — особливо, якщо йдеться про тлумачення слова. У даному випадку (можливо) згодилися б, окрім лінгвістичних, також юридичні джерела — але ні тих, ні інших автор не наводить.

Comment: Але ж ми кажемо *незаконні угрупування* і *незаконний обіг зброї* маючи на увазі такі, що прямо заборонені законом?

Comment: @Sasha - так, буде незаконно. Якщо ці дії не носитимуть масового характеру чи не заважатимуть іншим думаю ніхто не підніматиме питання, якщо це бізнес, як то вулична музика - можуть з заздрощів чи шуму юрби під вікнами підняти.

Comment: @Sasha {незаконні (у широкому розумінні)} = {юридично необґрунтовані} ∪ {протизаконні} . Ні, думаю ∪ зайве. Угода може бути повністю законною, повністю посилатися на конкретні закони, регуляторні акти, але містити один пункт протизаконний (що суперечить врегульованому законом питанню). Поняття незаконний і протизаконний в загальному випадку не перетинаються, інакше б дійсно це був майже синонім

Comment: @Yola у нас "протизаконні" кажуть зазвичай щоб викликати сприйняття слухача що існує звинувачення. Протизаконним збройне угрупування може бути визнаним за фактом протиправної діяльності чи способом володіння зброєю. Незаконним - просто за фактом відсутності статуту, структури, непрозорості. Так рух добровольців був незаконним на початку (і був підпорядкований МВС щоб це врегулювати), а рухи "руськой вєсни" - протизаконним за фактами своїй дій і декларованій ідеології поваленні конституційного ладу насильницким шляхом та сепаратизму

Comment: @MykolaMykolayovichDolynskyi, «чи не заважатимуть іншим» — але ж якщо ці дії заважатимуть іншим, то їх називатимуть незаконними не через те, що вони _не описані в законі_, а через те, що вони _заважають іншим_ (порушують закони про ведення комерційної діяльності або закон про тишу).

Comment: @MykolaMykolayovichDolynskyi, «поняття незаконний і протизаконний в загальному випадку не перетинаються» — ось із цим я категорично незгоден, я вважаю, що якщо щось протизаконне, то воно точно й незаконне — але, на жаль, послатися ні на що не можу.

Comment: @Sasha при слуханні справи про дії які створюють незручності для інших без їхної згоди такі дії слід називати "незаконними", але не можна назвати "протизаконними", якщо ці дії прямо не заборонено законом чи постановую чи рішенням. Якщо ж заборонено то на перший план виходить саме розгляд як "протизаконних дій", де факти незручностей для інших є просто обставинами що можуть впливати на міру відповідальності чи внутрішнє переконання судді. Закон про тишу дуже гарний приклад. Про комерційну діяльність - це може бути швидше за все боротьба між нелегальними підприємцями. За виключенням "наливайок"

Comment: @Sasha ваше право непогоджуватись, але спробую ще один приклад пояснити. Уявімо трапилась нова держава. І звісно вона хоче контроль над власним кордоном. Видає закон - "всі люди мають перетинати кордон через смугасті будки. Крапка". Все - у нас є порядок законний, який визнають держоргани. Але люди ходять сотні років як ближче і досі ходять. Цей порядок існуює де-факто, але де-юри став "незаконний". При тому не став "протизаконний" адже текст закону фактичний порядок не забороняв. І державні органи просто відмовлять в послугах на підставі "незаконного".

Comment: Останній приклад зовсім не зрозумів. Вони ж порушують закон про перетин кордону, отже ж, за моїм розумінням Вашої логіки, чинять *проти*законні дії, хіба ні?

Comment: @Sasha Ні, не порушують, оскільки закон прямо не забороняє інші способи перетину, не передбачає відповідальність. Є дві парадигми: "все що не заборонено - дозволено" - "демократичного" світу і "все що прямо не дозволено - забороненого" - тоталітарного світу. От ми понад 70 років прожили в другому, тому склалась традиція і внутрішнє переконання дотримуватись другого варіанту.

Comment: Щодо «оскільки закон прямо не забороняє інші способи перетину» — але ж Ви самі писали: «всі люди мають перетинати кордон через смугасті будки. Крапка». Щодо «все що не заборонено — дозволено» — саме так, тому мене й дивує, як можна те, що не заборонено, називати незаконним.